# How to test viewing restricted contents in AWS using signed cookies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a cloudfront distribution and configured with restrict viewer access. So i'm just looking for a way to view the contents within the distribution by assigning the cookies. I've manage to generate the below signed cookies.
{
"CloudFront-Policy":
"CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id":
"CloudFront-Signature":
}

Can we just call the cloudfront destination(https://d1fzlamzw9yswb.cloudfront.net/17-Sep-201%3A05%3A48_1.jpg) in browser and test it whether it works by assigning cookies from browser? What is the best way to test whether the signed cookies are working or not?

Comment: Can you access the content without the signed cookie?

Comment: @StefanN if i remove the restrict viewer access from the distribution, I can access the content without signed cookies. But after I enable the restrict viewer access option I could not access the content without signed cookies. What I need to know is a way to test this by assigning the cookies and how can I assign the cookies for testing.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve your problem with my answer?

Comment: @StefanN these are my 3 cookies. CloudFront-Policy": "eyJTdGF0ZW1.." , "CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id": "K2F5VZ9..", "CloudFront-Signature": "D81Wi2zIcC9O4c4i4puc...", and this is my cloufront url https://d1fzlamzw9yswb.cloudfront.net/ , I want to access a file using this url https://d1fzlamzw9yswb.cloudfront.net/file . How can I do this ? Im not clear about the answer you have given

Comment: I have edited the answer with a concrete example. Please check if it helps solve the issue now.

Comment: @StefanN Thanks for you answer I've managed to test the signed cookies and it is working. I do have another concern. Can we assign cookies from the application domain to cloudfrount distribution domain.  How can I achieve this since i need to access media files which is in the cloudfront distribution by assigning the cookies. But since my application domain is different I cant assign cookies to cloudfront distribution. You can refer this. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68125955/how-to-access-restricted-media-files-using-signed-cookies-from-cloud-front-distr) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you already created a signed cookie.

You can use curl to send cookies to your CloudFront distribution. This is one way of testing if your setup works correctly. Here is how to pass a cookie with your request:

`curl -b 'session=session_id' https://yourdistribution.cloudfront.net`

The full header that curl sets for this request looks like this `Cookie: session=session_id`

**UPDATE:**
Concretely, CloudFront will expect the following cookie set:

`curl -v -X GET --output test-file  -b "CloudFront-Expires=4762454400" -b "CloudFront-Signature=k9CxLm0HL5v6bx..." -b "CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=APKA..." "https://yourdistribution.cloudfrontnet/test-file"`

**Alternatively**, we can also use `--cookie` flag, like this:

`curl -v -X GET --output test-file  --cookie "CloudFront-Expires=4762454400;CloudFront-Signature=k9CxLm0HL5v6bx...;CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=APKA..." "https://yourdistribution.cloudfrontnet/test-file"`

Best, Stefan