# How to access restricted media files using signed cookies from cloud front distribution which uses a different domain from the application domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, cross-domain, amazon-cloudfront

Can we assign cookies from the application domain to a different domain. For example we need to access the restricted media files which use the d1fzlamzw9yswb.cloudfront.net  distribution, but if we run the application in localhost or in any other domain it does not allow us to assign the cookies to  d1fzlamzw9yswb.cloudfront.net programmatically. It normally sets the cookies to the application domain.

Somehow by manually assigning the cookies from the browser to d1fzlamzw9yswb.cloudfront.net  we were able to access the content without any issue.

So if the application runs in another domain (localhost or any other) how can we assign the cookies to a different domain where we need to access the restricted media files? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So you want to set a cookie for domain X on form a server running behind domain Y?

Comment: @StefanN Yes, the application is running on a different domain. And I want to assign the cookies to the cloudfront distribution which uses another domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting cookies for different domains is obviously not allowed.

However, one can use an apex domain in a signed cookie, for example, `.example.com`. If properly set this cookie will always be sent to any request made to example.com, but also to any of its subdomains, e.g., `cloudfront.example.com`. So we can take advantage of this and have our backend service, which is running on `backend.example.com` create and set a signed cookie for `.example.com`. Later when the frontend requests a file form  `cloudfront.example.com` it will automatically include the signed cookie with the request.

This approach requires having a custom domain for a Cloud Front distribution. Here [docs how to do that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Best, Stefan

Comment: Thanks alot. I was also thinking of this approach. And now I can start working on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Hi, my application is running on dev.***.com.lk domain. And I have set my cookies to the domain like this. (document.cookie = name +"=" + value + ";expires=" + expires+ ";domain=.dev.***..com.lk;path=/";). The cookies are there for all the requests that uses the main domain but when im sending a request to sub.***.com.lk domain which is a sub domain my cookies not present in the request headers. But it should be right.? What could be the issue for this?

Comment: Well `sub.example.com` us **not** a subdomain of `dev.example.com'. you need a cookie on `.example.com`.

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake there, actually my subdomain is sub.dev.***.com still the cookies are not being set. Access to video at 'https://drm.dev.***.rumex.com.lk/test.mp4' from origin 'https://dev.***.rumex.com.lk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. This is the error im getting.